# Subset an xts by year into a list. Subset an xts by year and month into a list

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

im new to R and the stack platforms.

```
sti <- getSymbols("^STI", src = "yahoo", auto.assign = F, from = "2007-01-01", to = "2017-12-31")
sti_adjusted <- sti[, 6]
```

I done this in order to subset the data into a list of years.

```
ls_sti_adjusted <- list(sti_adjusted["2007"], sti_adjusted["2008"], sti_adjusted["2009"], sti_adjusted["2010"], sti_adjusted["2011"], sti_adjusted["2012"], sti_adjusted["2013"], sti_adjusted["2014"], sti_adjusted["2015"], sti_adjusted["2016"], sti_adjusted["2017"])
```

I'm looking for a more elegant solution, like a for-loop maybe?

```
ls_sti_adjusted <- list()
for (i in 2007:2017){
ls_sti_adjusted[[]] <- ???
}
```

The second issue is how can I further subset the elements into months in the year?

so for example: `ls_sti_adjusted[[1]][[2]][[3]]` returns the 3rd data point of February in 2007. Is this possible?

I hope that I am clear about the problem that I am facing. Thanks folks, plus any tips/tricks to understand loops and lists better would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining `.indexyear` and `split(x,f = “months”` will give you the desired list.

```
lapply(unique(.indexyear(STI)),function(x) split.xts(STI[.indexyear(STI) == x ,],f='months’))
```

If you only need yearly lists leave out the `split` part, like so:

```
lapply(unique(.indexyear(STI)),function(x) STI[.indexyear(STI) == x ,])
```

UPDATE: OP’s follow-up question regarding naming of lists

Assuming you named the list of lists object `STIlist` you can do the following to name the list by years.( keep in mind that the names are converted to strings! )

```
names(STIlist) <- 2007:2018
```

To get the list of the year 2007:

```
> both(STIlist[['2007']])
           STI.Open STI.High STI.Low STI.Close STI.Volume STI.Adjusted
2007-01-03  3015.74  3037.74 3010.22   3037.74  192739200      3037.74
2007-01-04  3035.08  3045.18 3008.23   3023.80  198216700      3023.80
2007-01-05  3031.09  3038.27 3000.50   3029.04  233321400      3029.04
           STI.Open STI.High STI.Low STI.Close STI.Volume STI.Adjusted
2007-12-27  3469.11  3491.65 3459.97   3477.20   91474200      3477.20
2007-12-28  3452.18  3463.38 3441.96   3445.82  109442100      3445.82
2007-12-31  3424.48  3482.30 3424.48   3482.30  205741900      3482.30
```

If you need need more information about naming lists "Google is your best friend” or post another question :-)

Comment: Thank you! these worked. Is it also possible to rename the elements while carrying out these steps?

Comment: @DerekM.Chatman , I am not sure what you mean by “rename the elements”. Can you be more specific?

Comment: For example, if i view the head of the list, instead of seeing [[1]][[2]], it shows [[2007]][[Feb]], or something along these lines. Do i make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much. What a great community this is :-)

Comment: If this works, please consider to accept the solution by clicking on the tick mark next to the vote.

Answer (score 0):

for the first question something like this?

```
library(lubridate)
index(sti_adjusted)=floor_date(index(sti_adjusted),unit="years")
ls_sti_adjusted <- lapply(unique(index(sti_adjusted)),function(x) sti_adjusted[index(sti_adjusted)==x,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use the indexing directly from `xts`, check `?index.xts`:

```
split(sti_adjusted, .indexyear(sti_adjusted))
```

In order to keep the correct naming 2012, 2013, ..., we can try:

```
split(sti_adjusted, as.integer(format(index(sti_adjusted), '%Y')))
```

Of course this can be nested in a list as much as you want:

```
nestedList <- lapply(
  split(sti_adjusted, .indexyear(sti_adjusted))
  , function(x) split(x, .indexmon(x))
)
nestedList[[3]][[2]][3] #3.year, 2.month, 3. obs.
```

Example using build-in data from `xts`:

```
data(sample_matrix, package = "xts")
sample_matrix <- as.xts(sample_matrix)

nestedList <- lapply(
  split(sample_matrix, .indexyear(sample_matrix))
  , function(x) split(x, .indexmon(x))
)
nestedList[[1]][[3]][5]
               Open    High      Low    Close
2007-03-05 50.26501 50.3405 50.26501 50.29567
```

Comment: Thank you! The first code worked and it seems so simple. I seem to be having problems with the second code. The error is "subscript is out of bounds". I checked the structure of the nestedList and it says that each element of the nestedList is a list of 1 instead of a list of 12. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Hey Derek, I'm not quite sure what is happening. I provided a reproducible test example too.

Comment: Hey J.R. I've tried applying the code to my dataset and some subsetting conditions still return that subscripts are out of bounds, specifically any number for i >1 in the supposed "months" subset, i.e nestedListed[[1]][[i]][[1]]. Nevertheless hvollmeier has provided a solution below. Thanks for introducing the split function and helping me with my first problem.